# Amazon SQS vs Kafka Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've been migrating my self-hosted project to AWS Services. Currently I am migrating the message queue (I am currently using KAFKA) to SQS, I noticed that there was something related to "group ids" as well i KAFKA and SQS.

How can I subscribe as a consumer for a group in SQS? Is it possible?

In producers I have to set the GROUP_ID, but I dont know how to recover the message from a consumer group mutually exclusive.

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a way of doing it?

Comment: actually no :( 

Kind of the actual role of SQS is to act as, well, a queue. And so I had to choose an alternative, that is using Redis streams or AWS MKS